# Scope items in SharePoint modern pages search results page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Can we scope the search page of Modern SharePoint pages search results page?

[image]

When we do a search in the modern sharepoint pages, it goes to the below page which we will not be able to edit

> https://sitename.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/search.aspx/siteall?q=test

Is there a way to exclude lists/libraries of few sites from this search results page?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to completely exclude a list or library from Search results is to change one of the options under Advanced settings in the list settings to exclude showing them in Search Results.

**OR**

You could write PowerShell that would walk through the entire farm and change this setting on each list/library.

[Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e78aaff3-deaa-4d70-a0b8-92ba09bd8ca4/exclude-lists-and-libraries-from-search-results?forum=sharepointsearch)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to define a scope for modern search.

If you don't want items of some lists/libraries to show in search result, you can go to the List/Library settings->Advanced Settings, find **Search** section, and set it to **No**.
[image]